# Need the process to abort at a particular time

Tags: shell, unix

I have a scenario wherein the file will arrive at any time between 11:30 and 11:40. I can schedule a script to run to start at 11:30 to check if the file has arrived. Here is what I have with me.

```
i=0
while [ i -eq 0 ]
do
    if [ ! -f $File_Check_Dir/$FILE_NAME ] ; then
        echo " \n File has arrived at `date +'%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'****" | tee -a ${LOGFILE}
        i=1
    fi
done
```

I can make the script run in background. But I would need to check the systime and send an alert if the file has not arrived till 11:40 ET. I tried with systime functions but cant exactly get what I wanted.

Comment: Why not wait until 11:41 and just get the file or report an error?

Comment: Yup.  I would 1) have what process is downloading the file log when the arrival occurs (if possible), then 2) simply schedule one script at 11:41 to check whether it arrived or not (and send an e-mail or other alert)

Comment: It wont work out. I have a process starting exactly at 11:40 and that would start processing and removing the file from the directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of suggested ways to do this:

1. If running on a system with inotify support, use a tool such as `inotifywait` (from the Debian `inotify-tools` package) to be notified immediately of changes to your watched directory/file.  You can use the `-t` option to time out if no action occurs within the specified timeout period.  If using this tool, you'd may have to take care of race conditions between checking of the existence of your file in your shell script and running the `inotifywait` command.
2. Wrap your script using the `timeout` command.  eg. `timeout 10m my-watch-script`.  If the timeout occurs before the script exits, then `timeout` will return exit code 124 which you can then test to determine if a timeout occured, or the file was found.
3. If using bash, test the in-built `SECONDS` variable as part of your loop condition and exit when the timer expires.  If bash isn't available, a substitute would be to use the `date` command, and have it format output in seconds.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17310810/302243).

As it stands, the presented code runs in a very tight polling loop.  It'd be a good idea to put a `sleep` in there somewhere.

Comment: inotify tools are not available in the environment in which I work on and I use kshell. Can you elaborate on the timeout command? You mean to use, while scheduling in the cron, I need to place the timout?

Comment: @user2522824 You could place the `timeout` command in crontab, but it's likely that you'll need to take some other action if a timeout occurs.  If you do need to take some other action, you'd be best to have a wrapper script that cron executes, and within the wrapper would be a call to `timeout your-script`.

Comment: Ya got it. Thanks Austin :)

Comment: I am not able schedule it with the timeout option. Can you give me the exact command?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the time with `date +"%H:%M"` then you can add one more "if" to check if this is greater 11:40 and exit after sending the appropriate notification..

Comment: This is much simpler..i=0
while [ i -eq 0 ]
do
if [ date +%H:%M -eq 11:46 ]
echo " \n Pearson File has not arrived " | tee -a ${LOGFILE}
exit

if [ ! -f $File_Check_Dir/$Pearson_DATA_FILE_NAME ] ; then
echo " \n File has arrived at `date +'%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'****" | tee -a ${LOGFILE}
i=1
fi
done
IS it ok?

Comment: Looks good at a quick glance. Did you try running it with a test file ?

Comment: It looks like date +"H:%M" doesnt work in the script. I tried giving the same in command line. It works then.

Comment: Hmm I don't see why it would behave differently in a script. You have to check your syntax maybe store the value in a variable? use quotes correctly?

Answer (score 0):

One possible option:

In your script:

```
trap sendMailFunction SIGUSR1
sendMailFunction(){
.
. # Enter your code here, which will send mail in case the file does not arrive in time
.
}
.
. # Remainder of the script....
```

& Run it under `timeout` at 11:30 (Using `at` or `cron`, as your requirement.)

```
timeout -s SIGUSR1 10m /path/to/myscript.sh arg1 arg2 arg3 ...
```

Comment: Can you give me the command for scheduling in cron with the timeout option?